# Symfony 2 run on server table name error

Tags: php, mysql, database, doctrine, symfony

Im trying to run symfony 2 app on server and i have an error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'Slider' 
doesn't exist
```

But table exists in database. Thing is that the table name is 'slider' not 'Slider'.
`I dont want to change names of all tables.`
Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rename all your table to match Entity names, or you can change the definition in your entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 */
class Foo
{
}
```

Comment: I already done this. But now im curious, that there is other, quicker solution.

Comment: So that is a MySQL issue. Try to look at this document http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably have developed the application on a case insensitive OS like Windows or OSX, and now deploy to a linux server, am I right? The only way to prevent this from happening is to define the tablename in your entity class, with the Table annotation:

```
@ORM\Table(name="Slider")
```